# ¿Cómo llenar List<SqlParameter> y especificar parámetros output's?

Tags: c#, funciones, lista, stored-procedure

Estoy realizando una función generica en C# para ejecutar procedimientos de almacenados.

Hasta ahora tengo este código:

```
public DataTable ejecutar_procedimientos_genericos(string nombre_procedimiento, List<SqlParameter> parametros)
        {
            DataTable tabla_datos = new DataTable();

            //Variable que identifica si se realizó el proceso. 
            bool correcto = false;

            SqlTransaction Transaccion = null;

            int Valor_Retornado = 0;

            try
            {
                //funcion que abre la conexion. 
                abrir_conexion();

                Transaccion = sql_conexion.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable);

                //"sql_conexion" : contiene mi conexion,
                // la obtengo cuando ejecuto la función abrir_conexion();
                SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(nombre_procedimiento, sql_conexion, Transaccion);

                comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                //comando.Parameters.Clear();

                if (parametros != null)
                    comando.Parameters.AddRange(parametros.ToArray());

                SqlDataAdapter data_adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);

                data_adapter.Fill(tabla_datos);

                Valor_Retornado = Convert.ToInt32(comando.Parameters["@return_value"].Value);

                if (Valor_Retornado == 0)
                    correcto = true;
            }
            catch (SqlException excepcion)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ha ocurrido un error  en la operacón. " + "\n\nDetalles del Error:\n\n"
                                     + excepcion.Message, "ERROR PROCESANDO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            catch (Exception excepcion)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ha ocurrido un error  en la operacón. " + "\n\nDetalles del Error:\n\n"
                                     + excepcion.Message, "ERROR PROCESANDO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (correcto)
                {
                    Transaccion.Commit();

                    //función que cierra la conexión
                    cerrar_conexion();
                }
                else //si se presentó algun error
                {
                    Transaccion.Rollback();

                    //función que cierra la conexión
                    cerrar_conexion();
                }
            }
            return tabla_datos;
        }
```

En esta parte del código:

> if (parametros != null)
>
> comando.Parameters.AddRange(parametros.ToArray());

**¿Entonces a la lista cómo puedo especificarle el tipo de dato del parámetro y si hay parámetro de salida o de retorno?**

como si declararan de forma normal sin la lista ejemplo así:

```
comando.Parameters.Add("@codigo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

comando.Parameters.Add("@return_value", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

Comment: No voy a poner una respuesta, pero voy a decirte porque es una mala idea. Estas encapsulando todos los errores en un messagebox, estas re haciendo algo que ya esta hecho (para algo esta el objeto conexion), no le estas aportando valor (salvo meterlo en una transaccion?). En realidad, estas complejizando algo, que de otra forma seria simple. vos estas seguro que esto te soluciona algo???

Comment: @gbianchi , los MessageBox es algo que puedo quitar no hay problema en quitarlos, **¿puedes sugerirme una forma mejor en la que pueda de forma genérica ejecutar procedimientos de almacenado y poder setear los parámetros de Salida o retorno? **

Comment: Puedo seguir mostrandote fallos sobre tratar de generalizar algo que no sabes si va a servir. Este procedimiento por ejemplo no se puede usar si necesito ejecutar dos SP consecutivos en una sola transaccion. Si, la sugerencia que tengo es no hagas cosas genericas a menos que estes totalmente seguro que cubren absolutamente todos los casos.

Comment: @gbianchi , es lo que intento poder hacerla y adaptarla a distintos casos de uso, estoy para aprender, tantos las buenas criticas como las malas son buenas porque te ayudan a crecer y eso es lo que intento.

Comment: otra cosa. Si solo vas a ejecutar select, para que necesitas las transacciones? porque por lo que se ve, tus SP no son updates o deletes..

Comment: Ok. Si esto es solo un procedimiento para aprender, esta perfecto y la pregunta es valida. Pero aclara que no es un proceso productivo por favor.

Comment: @gbianchi, voy a ejecutar : **Select, Update, Delete, y Select de Multiples Result Set** primero debo hacer que funcione y luego hago que sea multifuncional para distintos casos de uso.

Comment: A menos que todos tus procedimientos estén diseñados con un patrón idéntico, estoy de acuerdo con @gbianchi que probablemente no ganes mucho en tratar de diseñar un código genérico para ejecutar todos tus procedimientos, hasta puedes salir perdiendo. En particular su argumento de que no puedas combinar mas de una ejecución en la misma transacción me parece muy importante. Por la pregunta anterior que habías hecho, sé que no estás trabajando en el ambiente más cómodo, pero aun así, te animo a prestar atención a estos consejos muy pertinentes de gbianchi.

Comment: @sstan correcto, como vez me estoy viendo forzado a implementar métodos extraños, mi ambiente de trabajo no es cómodo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El equivalente a:

```
comando.Parameters.Add("@codigo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 2).Direction =
    ParameterDirection.Output;

comando.Parameters.Add("@return_value", SqlDbType.Int).Direction =
    ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

... pero usando una lista de `SqlParameter` sería sencillamente:

```
var listaParams = new List<SqlParameter>();

listaParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@codigo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 2)
                {
                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
                });

listaParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@return_value", SqlDbType.Int)
                {
                    Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
                });
```

---

Comentarios no directamente relacionados a tu pregunta:

- Evita usar una conexión global como pareces estar haciendo. Esto va a resultar en defectos sutiles si llegas a usar esto en una aplicación multi-hilos.
- ¿Estás seguro que quieres emplear el isolation level *Serializable*? Lo más común es usar *Read Committed* ya que *Serializable* tiende a generar más errores cuando hay concurrencia.
- ¡Muy importante! No te olvides de usar bloques `using` alrededor de tus instancias de `SqlTransaction`, `SqlTransaction`, `SqlCommand`, etc para evitar un *leak* de recursos.

Comment: probaré esta solución.  con respecto a esto : _Evita usar una conexión global como pareces estar haciendo. Esto va a resultar en defectos sutiles si llegas a usar esto en una aplicación multi-hilos_ tengo una clase que maneja la conexión. Uso _isolation level Serializable_ por desconocimiento, **Read Committed** investigaré como usar esto.

Comment: No importa que uses una clase separada para manejar la conexión, la pregunta es, si 2 hilos intentan ejecutar un procedimiento usando este método, ¿trabajarán con la misma conexión, o cada una trabajará en una conexión separada? Si ambos hilos trabajan en la misma conexión, tienes un problema.  En cuanto al `Read Committed` vs. `Serializable`, si no tienes preferencia, lo mejor es simplemente no especificar ese parámetro. Usualmente, el defecto es `Read Committed` de todas maneras.

Comment: **Si, usarían la misma conexión :( **, hasta ahora no me ha tocado ejecutar dos hilos que utilicen la conexión al mismo  tiempo, solo he ejecutado varios hilo para cumplir alguna función especifica pero no en cuanto a que deban usar la conexión , ahora he caído en cuenta. _Si sería un tremendo error usarla así_ tengo que ver de que manera entonces modificar esta parte para no usar la conexión de esta manera.

Answer (score 0):

Si estás pasando una lista de `SqlParameters`, deberías establecer en cada parámetro (cada item de la lista) su dirección, seteando la propiedad `Direction` de cada `SqlParameter`.  Personalmente opté por utilizar el método [DeriveParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.deriveparameters(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), y en lugar de pasar una lista de `SqlParameters` simplemente paso una lista de objetos con los valores.  Esto crea otros problemas (como por ejemplo el orden de los parámetros es importante), pero me pareció más simple en su momento.

EDIT

Yo haría algo así (cambiando el parámetro de `List<SqlParameters>` a `List<Object>`:

```
comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(comando);
int i = 0;

if(parametros != null)
{
    foreach (SqlParameter xPar in  comando.Parameters)
    {
        xPar.Value = parametros.ElementAt(i); // Acá hay que tener cuidado con el orden y la cantidad de parámetros.
        i++;
    }
};
```

C# no es mi fuerte... el punto es que el método `DeriveParameters` debería cargar la colección `Parameters` del objeto `comando` incluyendo la dirección de cada parámetro, si es input o output.  La lógica de cómo manejar los retornos debería ser relativamente sencilla, contando con esta información.

Comment: Con respecto al orden de los parámetros, me aseguraría de ordenarlos bien en la lista antes enviarlo a la función del procedimiento. **¿Puede proporcionar un ejemplo de como hacer esto en la lista? ** 
_"deberías establecer en cada parámetro (cada item de la lista) su  dirección, seteando la propiedad Direction de cada SqlParameter."_

Comment: Eso es lo que pensé.  Si voy a llamar un procedimiento, por lo menos tengo que saber en qué orden tengo que pasar los parámetros.  En realidad es de lo único que me preocupo.  Dejo que .NET se encarge de las demás propiedades (que se llenan llamando a DeriveParameters) y de la conversión automática de tipos de datos.  Lo que no tengo claro es si DeriveParameters obtiene la dirección de un parámetro o no, pero deberia ser fácil de verificar.

Comment: comprendo pero no se como usar esa información que me estas proporcionando, no lo veo claro.

Comment: **Considero que de esa manera seria menos óptima agregando los parámetros uno por uno con el ciclo** y estaría en la misma situación ¿Cómo voy a setear _Parameter Direction_ dentro de la _List<Object>_ ? , esa es la información que requiero poder identificarlo en la lista, de lo  demás dentro del procedimiento me encargo.

Comment: No necesitas setear Parameter direction en List<Object>, sólo lo necesitas en el objeto `comando`.  En la llamada `SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(comando);` debería quedar seteado.  Todo lo que tienes que hacer es traspasar los valores al mismo objeto y hacer la llamada al SP.  Coincido en que es menos óptimo que el `AddRange` que estabas utilizando, pero a menos que sean miles de parámetros no creo que impacte mucho.